# Best approach to convert XML (or general file with structure) to class model

Tags: c++, xml, file

**My goal:**
Having multiple classes/structs which represent the data structure of the xml file (or in general a structured file) in order to access the data more efficiently.

**Problem:**
What containers are good for this approach, e.g. `std::unordered_set` / `std::vector`? What should such a class/struct look like, i.e. constructor/members and what is the best way to access them? What algorithm is good for the conversion of a tree, e.g. `pugi::xml_document`, into classes/structs?

**What I don't want:**
An extra library for converting or accessing like this one:
[XML Data Binding](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-data-binder/what-is-xml-data-binding-part-1)

**What I did so far:**

```
struct A {
    // Just default constructor... or better like class B?
    explicit A() noexcept = default;
    std::string foo;
    long bar;
    static std::vector<B*> bs;
}

struct B {
    explicit B(std::string bfoo, long bbar) noexcept : bfoo(std::move(bfoo)), bbar(bbar) {};
    const std::string bfoo;
    const long bbar;
    // Is static good/bad/necessary?
    static std::unordered_set<std::string> cs;
}

main() {
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    // ... parsing

    // after parsing, do some algorithm to translate tree into a std::unordered_map<std::string, A*>
}
```

**Additional information:** I need to search for entries within the xml file very often and therefore have to run through the whole tree to find some note. After finding the note, I then need to get the related information (children and siblings). Therefore I think it is more efficient to convert the tree into my own classes/structs, put those entries into a `std::unordered_map` to access the data in O(1) time.

I don't need to write into that xml file. I just need to read the data. The file is around 14mb large.

I was thinking about a depth-first-search for the algorithm, but it feels that it will be become very complicated to safe nodes related to each other in those classes.

This question does not have to be answered specifically for xml files and could also answer a general approach for structured files to load into memory for a faster access.

[pugixml](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml) is used for parsing the file.

Comment: Converting XML structures to C++ data structures is possible but very time consuming (manual) or riddled with corner cases (automated). I would suggest a hybrid approach where you create a C++ "index" over your XML tree with a map of int/string to XML node along with accessors to extract information.

Comment: @Botje That's a very good idea. However I am still interested how you would construct such a class, especially how do you make sure that there is only on copy from the tree to the structure and keep it singleton and access the data without keep copying.

Comment: Referencing the XML nodes by pointer guarantees it's not a copy (but does have other lifecycle concerns). A sufficiently smart XML library might have some kind of reference counting mechanism for XML nodes too.

Comment: @Botje yes, I need to carry the tree through all classes in order to keep it alive and in order to be able to point to the nodes.

Comment: You can keep the tree in a heap allocation somewhere and remove it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason why hibernate has been invented: it is hugely used in Java, but it also exists in Delphi, so I believe something should exist for C++ too.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I think there are several libraries which can do it for me, e.g. XML Data binding libraries. However, I would like to understand how I can construct such classes myself and doing it correctly.